# Cairo and Qt integration

Tags: c++, qt, integration, cairo

I want to use Cairo graphics library whith Qt, but I can't find any documenattion. I just want to make the GUI whith Qt and use Cairo for drawing graphics in a Qt window.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Starting from cairo 1.17.8, the Qt support [will be removed upstream](https://lists.cairographics.org/archives/cairo/2021-May/029251.html).

### Old answer

Recent version of cairo supports Qt by allowing to draw to a surface created with `cairo_qt_surface_create(QPainter *painter)`: you can inspect the relevant header file [here](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/cairo/tree/src/cairo-qt.h). There's no documentation because this feature is still experimental and disabled by default (you should compile cairo yourself explicitely enabling the Qt support with `configure --enable-qt`.

Comment: I will surely try this, I really hope it work's because now I am trying GTK and It's not so good as Qt.

Comment: If you are using C++ I think you'll be more comfortable by using the [C++ bindings](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/index-info.html.en), not plain GTK+ itsself. Qt and QPainter, GTK+ and cairo, gtkmm and cairomm and any valid mix... depending on what you want they are all valid options.

Comment: the cairo qt surface does not work (yet) with Qt6 and requires a minor fix to work with Qt5.

Answer (score 8):

[Qt's Paint System](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/paintsystem.html) is a very good drawing library and **is** vector based. And it's already there. If you pick Qt as your GUI toolkit, it can't get any easier.

Comment: @amc That is not correct. Most paint devices are raster-based, but [there are vector devices too](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qpaintengine.html#Type-enum): for instance, [QPdfWriter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qpdfwriter.html). The `QPainter` API itself is mostly comprised of vector-based operations. It's not simply a blitter.

Comment: the answer is 100% right, if you can avoid it, don't use cairo in your Qt app.

Answer (score 4):

***Caveat***: This is not going to be the answer you are looking for.

Are you sure you want this? To what end? Is this about writing a `QPaintDevice` based on Cairo? Qt has its own graphics primitives implemented and so does Cairo. The only reason I can see is that you don't want the a heavy layer of Qt interfere with your system (embedded?). It's like you are trying to use the DirectFB backend of Cairo -- but then there's stuff like Qt-on-DirectFB. However, note such an implementation is costly and not free without its own set of quarks such as library-interop issues, printing from this Cairo based context etc. I'd suggest you do a regular search on Google to figure if such efforts are/ever were underway and weigh the pros and cons very heavily before even attempting the same.

Comment: Thank's for the answer.

I just want a simple graphics library and a GUI library that can work togheter very easly, and I don't want to use the GUI library functions for drawing, I like Cairo because it's simple to use and It's vector based. Maybe you can recomend me another GUI library.

Comment: This is the part I don't understand, why don't you want to use Qt? Maybe, we can suggest an alternative then. Qt is more than GUI. Graphics libraries are at a lower level of abstraction than GUI libraries. IMHO, You are taking a step back. GTK+ is another such GUI library (with a Cairo backend).

Comment: I will try Qt graphic functions. I tried GTK but it's a pain to use in projects.

Comment: Sometimes we write programs that are supposed to use Qt only for its in-house tools - and the rest is only cairo based. That is the reason why people may need to use cairo for painting in UI widgets made by qt.

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved by this dirty way:

1. Create an cairo image surface, draw on that surface.
2. Call cairo_image_surface_get_data() to get the pixels.
3. Copy the image to a Qt widget.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how it might be done:

```
class CairoWidget: public QWidget
{
public:
  using QWidget::QWidget;

private:
  void paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
  {
    auto const w(width()), h(height());
    QImage image(w, h, QImage::Format_RGB32);

    auto const surf(cairo_image_surface_create_for_data(image.bits(),
      CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24, w, h, image.bytesPerLine()));
    auto const cr(cairo_create(surf));
    cairo_surface_destroy(surf);

    //
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 1, 1, 1);
    cairo_paint(cr);
    cairo_scale(cr, w, h);

    //
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0);
    cairo_move_to(cr, 0, 0);
    cairo_line_to(cr, 1, 1);
    cairo_move_to(cr, 1, 0);
    cairo_line_to(cr, 0, 1);
    cairo_set_line_width(cr, .2);
    cairo_stroke(cr);

    cairo_rectangle(cr, 0, 0, .5, .5);
    cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, 1, 0, 0, .80);
    cairo_fill(cr);

    cairo_rectangle(cr, 0, .5, .5, .5);
    cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, 0, 1, 0, .60);
    cairo_fill(cr);

    cairo_rectangle(cr, .5, 0, .5, .5);
    cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, 0, 0, 1, .40);
    cairo_fill(cr);

    cairo_destroy(cr);

    //
    QPainter p(this);
    p.drawImage(0, 0, image);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  CairoWidget w;
  w.show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

[image]
There are other hacks you might try to attempt, such as drawing directly into the backing store or you can also initialize `QImage` from your own buffer, which would be preferable for a [custom](https://github.com/user1095108/cairowidget) `cairo` `QWidget`:

```
QImage::QImage(const uchar *data, int width, int height, int bytesPerLine, QImage::Format format, QImageCleanupFunction cleanupFunction = nullptr, void *cleanupInfo = nullptr)
```